# C++ passing std::unique_ptr as an argument

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I tried to implement binary tree using `std::unique_ptr` but errors come up and I don't understand the output error.

The code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class BinTreeNode {
public: 
    BinTreeNode(T key): data {key}, left {nullptr}, right {nullptr} {}
    ~BinTreeNode() {}
    T data;
    std::unique_ptr<BinTreeNode<T>> left;
    std::unique_ptr<BinTreeNode<T>> right;
};

template <typename T>
class BinTree {
public:
    BinTree() : root {nullptr} {} 
    ~BinTree() {}
    std::unique_ptr<BinTreeNode<T>> root;

    void insert(std::unique_ptr<BinTreeNode<T>> node, T key);
};

template <typename T>
void BinTree<T>::insert(
    std::unique_ptr<BinTreeNode<T>> node, 
    T key)
{
    if(node){ // != nullptr
        if(node->data < key) insert(node->right, key);
        else insert(node->left, key);
    } 
    else{
        std::unique_ptr<BinTreeNode<T>> u_ptr(new BinTreeNode<T>(key));
        node = std::move(u_ptr);
    }
}

int main(){
    BinTree<int> tree();
    tree.insert(tree.root, 10);
}
```

I assume the error is in insert function and is related to argument initialisation.

> BinTree.cpp:65:27: error: use of deleted function
>   ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp,
>   _Dp>&) [with _Tp = BinTreeNode; _Dp = std::default_delete >]’   tree.insert(tree.root, 10);
>                              ^
>
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/memory:81:0,
>                    from BinTree.cpp:2: /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unique_ptr.h:356:7: note: declared here
>          unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
>          ^
>
> BinTree.cpp:35:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void
>   BinTree::insert(std::unique_ptr >, T) [with T =
>   int]’  void BinTree::insert(
>         ^
>
> BinTree.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void
>   BinTree::insert(std::unique_ptr >, T) [with T =
>   int]’: BinTree.cpp:65:27:   required from here BinTree.cpp:40:47:
>   error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp,
>   _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = BinTreeNode; _Dp = std::default_delete >]’
>   if(node->data < key) insert(node->right, key);
>                                                  ^
>
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/memory:81:0,
>                    from BinTree.cpp:2: /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unique_ptr.h:356:7: note: declared here
>          unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
>          ^
>
> BinTree.cpp:35:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void
>   BinTree::insert(std::unique_ptr >, T) [with T =
>   int]’  void BinTree::insert(
>         ^
>
> BinTree.cpp:41:30: error: use of deleted function
>   ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp,
>   _Dp>&) [with _Tp = BinTreeNode; _Dp = std::default_delete >]’    else insert(node->left,
>   key);
>                                 ^
>
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/memory:81:0,
>                    from BinTree.cpp:2: /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unique_ptr.h:356:7: note: declared here
>          unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
>          ^
>
> BinTree.cpp:35:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void
>   BinTree::insert(std::unique_ptr >, T) [with T =
>   int]’  void BinTree::insert(

Comment: You forgot to tell us the error. What's happening ? Copy paste any output/error so everyone can see it.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is move-only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is caused by you trying to copy-construct the argument of `BinTree::insert` from `tree.root`. `std::unique_ptr` is move-only.

My guess is that `node` in `BinTree::insert` should be passed by reference. Reasons:

1. You'd have to `std::move` the `tree.root` into it (if passed by value), which would steal the ownership
2. You're move-assigning to it in `BinTree::insert`, these changes are not made to pass `tree.root`

Comment: @tomtom, make sure you understand what is actually happening there. While LogicStuff is likely correct in their guess, I am not sure if you fully understand the reasons for that.